# Custom validator in angular reactive forms is never firing

Tags: angular-reactive-forms

I have created a very simple custom validator for a simple form control, e.g. MatInput, which would always return non-null e.g. invalid. I hav also added one of the pre-built validators e.g. required. When I start my app I can see that `status = INVALID` and `errors.required = true`.

Once I start typing, I expected that status will remain `INVALID` and `errors.myError = true`, but this does not happen. What am I doing wrong? I have built my example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-og2h9b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). I have also added the contents on my TS & HTML files below

**TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl,  FormControl,  ValidationErrors,  ValidatorFn,  Validators} from '@angular/forms';

export function myValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      return { "myError": true };
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  name = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, myValidator]);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<label>
    Name:
    <input type="text" [formControl]="name">
</label>

{{ name | json }}
```

I am quite new to Angular and I am not sure how to debug this. What can I try next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR:

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, myValidator()]);
}
```

Explanation:

`myValidator` is not being called, so you are not getting the `ValidatorFn`

Comment: Wow! The answer is quite simple, but it works! I did not pay attention to this. So I was passing that "factory" function as argument rather than actually calling it (hence passing the ValidatorFn function). Thank you Nery!

Comment: why didn't I get an error! I thought TS takes care of such things since the function signature is different (myValidator vs ValidatorFn), right?

Comment: It should. But I haven't review the definitions, so I don't know why it doesn't catch this error. But I guess it's because the current implementation of FormControl accepts several types of arguments and Typescripts gives up. I know they are working in a new implementation.

Comment: If my answer helped you, consider marking as accepted.

Comment: It did help me. I am just new here too and did not notice this feature. I accepted the answer. Thanks again